# converting this sql query to correlated subquery

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

```
"SELECT *,RANK () OVER" + "( " +"ORDER BY " + TOTALSCORE_COL+ " )" +  SP + " FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES ;
```

I learnt that below is the correlated version of the above code

```
    "SELECT s1.*, " + 
    "(SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + " AS s2 WHERE s2." + TOTALSCORE_COL+ " < s1."  +  TOTALSCORE_COL+ ") AS SP "+
    "FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + " AS s1";
```

please please help me convert this similar code to corelated subquery.

```
"SELECT *,DENSE_RANK () OVER" + "( " +"ORDER BY " + TOTALSCORE_COL+ " )" +  SP + " FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES ;
```

Same code code but this time Dense Rank.

I want an output of the whole table plus a virtual(fake) column ranking the students.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the highest score ranked 1st, you must make a change to count the distinct number of scores:

```
"SELECT s1.*, " + 
"(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT " + TOTALSCORE_COL + 
") FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + 
" AS s2 WHERE s2." + 
TOTALSCORE_COL+ " >= s1." + TOTALSCORE_COL + ") AS SP "+
"FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + " AS s1";
```